# Unity iOS Build Local Notification while App in Foreground

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am currently designing an application in Unity (for iOS) in which a local notification is created when an in-game event is triggered. Right now, the local notification is only able to appear when the app is running in the background, not while the app is running in the foreground.

How might I go about allowing the notification to appear while the app is in the foreground?

I would prefer a solution within Unity itself and not within XCode, as I am more comfortable working in that platform.

For reference, the local notification is set up in this code:

```
public void ScheduleNotification()

{
    if (UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.localNotificationCount == 0) {

        UnityEngine.iOS.LocalNotification notif = new UnityEngine.iOS.LocalNotification();

        notif.fireDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);

        notif.alertBody = "Testing, testing, 123!";

        UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification(notif);

    }
}
```